# Image sharing on Whatsapp not working

Tags: android, share, whatsapp, whatsapi

I want to share image from my app to Whatsapp but it's giving me the error "*sharing failed , please try again*" this is my code:

```
String text = "Look at my awesome picture";
        Uri pictureUri = Uri.parse("file://www.punjabidharti.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/baap-600x600.jpg");
        Intent shareIntent = new Intent();
        shareIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, text);
        shareIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, pictureUri);
        shareIntent.setType("image/*");
        shareIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_GRANT_READ_URI_PERMISSION);
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(shareIntent, "Share images..."));
```

and I am using image url from my website.

Comment: check the pictureUri  , i think its not valid

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a http url not a file url. Make your uri like this and it will work

```
Uri pictureUri = Uri.parse("http://www.punjabidharti.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/05/baap-600x600.jpg");
```